# Как вывести информацию из таблицы в цикле (RedBean)

Tags: php, mysql

Ситуация такая, не могу допетрить как вывести информацию из таблицы применяя ORM RedBean, заранее благодарен

Шаблон PHP:

```
    <?php
    include 'bd.php';
    $single_region  = $_GET[single];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register_user WHERE region = '$single_region'");

    while ($ar = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo ""."<tr>
            <td><p class='array'>".$ar[region]."</td>
            <td>".$ar[uchname]."</td><td>".$ar[adress]."</td><td>".$ar[mp]."</td><td>".$ar[fio]."</td><td>".$ar[fiorab]."</td><td>".$ar[wname]."</td>
            <td>".$ar[email]."</td>"."</td>
            <td>".$ar[comment]."</td>".

            "<td> <a href='/files/".$ar[file_name]."'>Скачать</a></td>

            </tr>"."";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: P.S, где почитать о формировании массивов в RedBean и вывода их применяя цикличные выражения do, while?

Answer (score 0):

[Документацию читать](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/finding) не пробовали ?

P.s. где в вашем коде используется RedBean(вы ведь имели ввиду RedBeanPHP если я правильно понял вас), мне не понятно...

Как-то так должно работать, вроде

```
$register_users = R::findAll( 'register_user', ' region = :region ', [':region' => $single_region] );

if( $register_users ) {
    foreach( $register_users as $user ) {
        echo ""."<tr>
        <td><p class='userray'>".$user['region']."</td>
        <td>".$user['uchname']."</td><td>".$user['adress']."</td><td>".$user['mp']."</td><td>".$user['fio']."</td><td>".$user['fiorab']."</td><td>".$user['wname']."</td>
        <td>".$user['email']."</td>"."</td>
        <td>".$user['comment']."</td>".

        "<td> <a href='/files/".$user['file_name']."'>Скачать</a></td>

        </tr>"."";
    }
}
```

Comment: Читайте суть более внимательно. Я хочу переделать этот код с применением PDO.

Comment: Документацию эту читать как раз таки пробовал, но нужного не нашел, может вы покажете?

Comment: смотрите ниже, там есть метод findAll, он возвращает массив(просто многомерный или объектов я без понятия). Ну а дальше все просто - пргоняете его через свой любимый цикл - foreach как вариант.

Comment: добавил пример, должно работать.